# operator dot and value category propagation from object to its data member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, perfect-forwarding, c++17

There is [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf) of `operator .`. Can I achieve the following behaviour (in future), using user-defined `operator .` in some form?:

```
struct S { int i; };
S s;
// W is some imaginable wrapper, say, based on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117744/aggregate-wrapper
W< S > w = s; // std::reference_wrapper-like
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(std::move(w).i), int && >);
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(w.i), int & >);
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(std::as_const(w).i), int const & >);
```

I can even imagine some "new generation" `forward` function:

```
template< typename T >
W2< T && >
dot_forward(T && x)
{
    return x;
}
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(std::dot_forward(s).i), int & >);
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(std::dot_forward(std::move(s)).i), int && >);
static_assert(std::is_same_v< decltype(std::dot_forward(std::as_const(s)).i), int const & >);
```

Where `W2` is a class template with `W2(T &)` c-tor and user-defined `operator .`, specialized by "referenceness" (*rvalue* or *lvalue*) `template< typename T > class W< T && >;` and `template< typename T > class W< T & >;`.

Will it be possible to achieve using `operator .`?

Comment: I don't see anything in the proposal (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf is the most recent revision) that disallows the usual ref-qualifier + cv-qualifier overloads. Of course, this could change at any time.